White boy and girl with dark hair searching for a treasure in Peru
I am looking for the name of a movie possibly from the 80s or 90s. 
I remember a mother with her son. 
I remember a man with a girl with dark hair and a name sounding like Una. I think it's his daugther, but I am not sure. At some point in the movie the girl reads a Quipu.
Don't know in which relation the adults are, but the kids become friends. 
They have to deal with a few bad guys and are looking for some kind of treasure at some point in the movie. 
One of the final scenes plays near the airport, if I remember correctly. The girl and the boy are bidding farewell but deciding to hunt the treasure again for some reason. 
The movie seems to play mostly in south america, peru. 

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.
